# Combining list of list

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

Hello i have to programm this fucntion in lisp:

```
(defun combine-list-of-lsts (lst)...)
```

So when executing the function i should get

```
(combine-list-of-lsts '((a b c) (+-) (1 2 3 4)))

((A + 1) (A + 2) (A + 3) (A + 4) (A-1) (A-2) (A-3) (A-4) (B + 1) (B + 2) (B + 3) (B + 4) (B-1) (B-2) (B-3) (B-4)(C + 1) (C + 2) (C + 3) (C + 4) (C-1) (C-2) (C-3) (C-4))
```

What i have now is:

```
(defun combine-list-of-lsts (lst)
(if (null (cdr lst))
    (car lst)
(if (null (cddr lst))
        (combine-lst-lst (car lst) (cadr lst))
(combine-lst-lst (car lst) (combine-list-of-lsts (cdr lst))))))
```

Using this auxiliar functions:

```
(defun combine-lst-lst (lst1 lst2)
        (mapcan #'(lambda (x) (combine-elt-lst x lst2)) lst1))

(defun combine-elt-lst (elt lst)
            (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (list elt x)) lst))
```

But what i get with this:

```
((A (+ 1)) (A (+ 2)) (A (+ 3)) (A (+ 4)) (A(-1)) (A(-2)) (A(-3)) (A(-4))...)
```

I dont know how to make this but without the parenthesis

Comment: You might want to ident your code properly to see actually the structure of the code a bit better...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The first thing is to look at this case:

   (combine-list-of-lsts '((a b c)))

   What should that be? Maybe not what your function returns...
2. Then I would look at the function `combine-list-of-lsts`. Do you need two `IF` statements?
3. Then look at `combine-elt-lst`. Do you really want to use `LIST`? It creates a new list. Wouldn't it make more sense to just add the element to the front?

Comment: the function recieve a list of lists, 

I know that  in combine-elt-lst i am not suposse to use that becuase it creates parenthesis around the result, but i dont know what to use, thats why i am stack

Comment: @Megan.. it does. `((a b c))` is a list of lists: a list of one list. `()` is also a list of lists: a list of no lists. `((a b c) (d e f))` is also a list of lists: a list of two lists.

Comment: combine-elt-lst does not create parentheses around things. Parentheses are only created during printing as textual output...

Comment: is there any way that when combine-elt-lst prints the parenthese are not showing? 
Thanks!

Comment: @Megan.. Open your REPL and compare `(list 1 '(2 3))` to `(cons 1 '(2 3))`. Both are lists, but their structures are different.

Comment: combine-elt-lst does not print anything. It returns a list. You need to think in terms of list operations, not in terms of printing. None of your code does any printing and that's okay.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you so much! with that change now i get the result i want! You know the differences in the structures of list and cons?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when you want to reduce mutliple arguments into single result, you need function #'reduce. Your combination of lists has name cartesian n-ary product.

Following function:

```
(defun cartesian (lst1 lst2)
  (let (acc)
    (dolist (v1 lst1 acc)
      (dolist (v2 lst2)
        (push (cons v1 v2) acc)))))
```

creates cartesian product of two supplied lists as list of conses, where #'car is  an element of lst1, and #'cdr is an element of lst2.

```
(cartesian '(1 2 3) '(- +))

==> ((3 . -) (3 . +) (2 . -) (2 . +) (1 . -) (1 . +))
```

Note, however, that calling #'cartesian on such product will return malformed result - cons of cons and element:

```
(cartesian (cartesian '(1 2) '(+ -)) '(a))

==> (((1 . +) . A) ((1 . -) . A) ((2 . +) . A) ((2 . -) . A))
```

This happens, because members of the first set are conses, not atoms. On the other hand, lists are composed of conses, and if we reverse order of creating products, we could get closer to flat list, what is our goal:

```
(cartesian '(1 2)
           (cartesian '(+ -) '(a)))

==> ((2 + . A) (2 - . A) (1 + . A) (1 - . A))
```

To create proper list, we only need to cons each product with nil - in other words to create another product.

```
(cartesian '(1 2)
           (cartesian '(+ -)  
                      (cartesian '(a) '(nil))))

==> ((2 + A) (2 - A) (1 + A) (1 - A))
```

Wrapping everything up: you need to create cartesian product of successive lists in reversed order, having last being '(nil), what can be achieved with reduce expression. Final code will look something like this:

```
(defun cartesian (lst1 lst2)
  (let (acc)
    (dolist (v1 lst1 acc)
      (dolist (v2 lst2)
        (push (cons v1 v2) acc)))))

(defun combine-lsts (lsts)
  (reduce
   #'cartesian
   lsts
   :from-end t
   :initial-value '(nil)))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way you can try,

```
(defun mingle (x y)
 (let ((temp nil))
  (loop for item in x do
   (loop for it in y do
    (cond ((listp it) (setf temp (cons (append (cons item 'nil) it) temp)))
     (t (setf temp (cons (append (cons item 'nil) (cons it 'nil)) temp))))))
  temp))
```

Usage:`(mingle '(c d f) (mingle '(1 2 3) '(+ -)))` =>

`((F 1 +) (F 1 -) (F 2 +) (F 2 -) (F 3 +) (F 3 -) (D 1 +) (D 1 -) (D 2 +)
 (D 2 -) (D 3 +) (D 3 -) (C 1 +) (C 1 -) (C 2 +) (C 2 -) (C 3 +) (C 3 -))`